# Joomla Menu Subcategories only showing 4 items

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am able to show items in subcategories in a menu view in Joomla (finally - it was no easy task.)

But now it is only showing the first 4 of each subcategory.

Technically they are all secondary - and it should be showing all of them because I set max secondary on the subcategories to 100.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add more details of the issue. perhaps paste the code or so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right below should work for you.

It's under Blog Layout Options in the Edit Menu Item panel. I think I had confused it with a similar option under Category Options, "Subcategory Levels" where the tip says "The number of subcategory levels to display."

[Read more](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/menus/list-all-categories-options)